# how to integrate youtube video in Flex without using AS3 player

Tags: youtube, flex4, youtube-api

I would like fetch youtube videos using only Flex video player or any other media player, but not by using youtube AS3 player in Flex4.

I have referred this link

http://thanksmister.com/2007/04/27/flex-youtube-grabber/.

However for some reason it is not working.

Does youtube allows play video without using there AS3 player?

Answer (score 1):

The official way of doing this is the [ActionScript 3 player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference). It was pretty much designed for your scenario, so I'm not sure why you're reluctant to use it.

In general, please ensure that you abide by the [YouTube API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) and don't attempt to access YouTube content via any unofficial method.

Comment: I want to use it in Mobile application along with OSMF. here everything works fine, except full screen option. I have tried to set full screen option using setsize(). But it did not worked.  However if you use same vidoe with Adobe flex "vidoe player control" full screen works fine. so I thought of not using AS3 player